# Laravel orWhereIn multiple condition with enclosure

Tags: laravel-8

My table "companies" has some many columns including position_id, position_id1, position_id2. So I need in Laravel to generate AND condition with 2 ORs. So when I search for companies with any of position_ids=[1,2,3] I'd SQL query will be "...AND (c.position_id in (1,2,3) OR c.position_id1 in (1,2,3) OR c.position_id2 in (1,2,3))".
Here is my PHP code which doesn't work (different combinations):

```
$position_ids = [1,2,3];
$companies = $companies->whereIn(function ($q) use ($position_ids) {
                $q->whereIn('c.position_id', $position_ids)
                ->orWhereIn('c.position_id1', $position_ids)
                ->orWhereIn('c.position_id2', $position_ids);
            });
$companies = $companies->orWhereIn(function ($q) use ($position_ids) {
                $q->orWhereIn('c.position_id', $position_ids)
                ->orWhereIn('c.position_id1', $position_ids)
                ->orWhereIn('c.position_id2', $position_ids);
            });
$companies = $companies->whereIn(function ($q) use ($position_ids) {
                $q->orWhereIn('c.position_id', $position_ids)
                ->orWhereIn('c.position_id1', $position_ids)
                ->orWhereIn('c.position_id2', $position_ids);
            });
And all the combinations above are getting the same error:
```

I am getting: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereIn(), 1 passed in ...\app\Http\Controllers\CompanyController.php on line 621 and at least 2 expected.
How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

whereIn() function needs two argument

```
$companies->whereIn('id', function ($q) use ($position_ids) {
            $q->whereIn('c.position_id', $position_ids)
            ->orWhereIn('c.position_id1', $position_ids)
            ->orWhereIn('c.position_id2', $position_ids);
        });
```